# Why can I not load my Haskell file into ghci via terminal?

Tags: haskell

I'm just beginning to learn Haskell and have already look through for existing answers so don't shoot me down for this, but why am I unable to load a `.hs` file in the terminal using `:load -W filename.hs`?

The code that I have in the file is:

```
doubleList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleList list = case list of 
[] -> []
(x:xs) -> x*2:list xs
```

How do I load this file into ghci and then use the correct format to add the list of integers as the arguement?

Comment: What is `:load -W`? Have you tried `:load filename.hs`? This has always worked. If it doesn't, what happens exactly when you try it?

Comment: if your file is like this - it is invalid haskell and you should get an error - which you should inform us about. (first of all it is incorrectly indented, and secondly you try to apply `list` to `xs` - I think you should use `doubleList xs`)

Comment: I guess the `-W` is for enabling warnings, which is a good thing. For that, you can use in GHCi `:set -W`. After that, you can load the file with `:l file.hs`. Warnings can also be enabled in the source file, adding `{-# OPTIONS -W #-}` at the very top of the file.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I'm just starting out so appreciate the pointers.

Comment: Why the -3 for this question though?  Is there something wrong with how I structured it or should only people that know how to program post questions here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, your code is badly aligned. The various branches of a `case ... of` have to be indented to tell Haskell that they 'belong' to it. Which means you should write:

```
doubleList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleList list = case list of 
  [] -> []
  (x:xs) -> x*2:list xs
```

Then, in the expression `x*2:list xs` you are applying `list` of type `[Integer]` to `xs` of type `[Integer]` too. This just won't typecheck. You presumably meant to write a recursive call to the *function* `doubleList`. Which means you should write:

```
doubleList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleList list = case list of 
  [] -> []
  (x:xs) -> x*2:doubleList xs
```

As for the `-W` option, loading files in `ghci` is a bit different then typechecking them using `ghc`: you cannot pass arguments to `:load` as you would `ghc`. As @chi explained, you have to use `:set` to set flags.